# Convert a string to a matrix in C#

Tags: c#, string, multidimensional-array, split

I have a string like this:

```
 people="Prof. Dr. Bill Gates;bill@microsoft.com;Microsoft Corporation!
 Dr. Elon Musk;elon@tesla.com;Tesle Inc.!
 Dr.Mehdi Karakoç;mehdi@tetra.com.tr;Tetra Yazılım!";
```

And I want to convert this data to 3x3 matrix like below:

```
Prof. Dr. Bill Gates    bill@microsoft.com  Microsoft Corporation 
Assoc. Dr. Elon Musk    elon@teslacar.com   Tesle Inc. 
Dr. Mehmet Mehdi Kara   mehdi@tetra.com.tr  Tetra Yazılım
```

Each '!' is an 'End of Line' and ';' is the end of each elements
How can I do this in a simple way?

Comment: So? Have you tried anything yet? What isn't working with what you have tried? (SO is not a code service site..)

Comment: `string.Split(';')`

Comment: var simple = people.Split('!').Where(p => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p)).Select(p => p.Split(';')).ToArray();

Answer (score 1):

use str.split();

```
var people = @"Prof. Dr. Bill Gates;bill@microsoft.com;Microsoft Corporation!Dr.Elon Musk; elon @tesla.com; Tesle Inc.!Dr.Mehdi Karakoç; mehdi @tetra.com.tr; Tetra Yazılım!";

        var person = people.Split('!');

        foreach (var item in person)
        {
            var data = item.Split(';');

            var name = data[0];
            var email = data[1];
            var company = data[2];

            --> Here Add Itens on your Matriz or List

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Matrix objects, but this is how you would parse that string into a 2d string array. Hope it helps get you on the right track.

```
string people = "Prof. Dr. Bill Gates;bill@microsoft.com;Microsoft Corporation!Dr.Elon Musk; elon @tesla.com; Tesle Inc.!Dr.Mehdi Karakoç; mehdi @tetra.com.tr; Tetra Yazılım!";
string[] tmp;
int maxWidth = 0;
int row;
List<string[]> everybody = new List<string[]>();
string[] folks = people.Split('!');
string[,] matrix;

foreach (string person in folks)
{
    tmp = person.Split(';');
    maxWidth = Math.Max(maxWidth, tmp.Length);
    everybody.Add(tmp);
}

matrix = new string[everybody.Count, maxWidth];
row = 0;

foreach (string[] body in everybody)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < maxWidth; i++)
    {
        if (i < body.Length)
        {
            matrix[row, i] = body[i];
        }//if this person has enough entries
    }//for each value in person
    row++;
}//for each person

//Result is now a 2 dimensional string array, parsed per value per person.
```